# How to add box shadow around the below shape

Tags: html, css

Hi Guys i am trying to add a box shadow around the custom shape created using css 
like the below image

[image]

```css
body{
   padding:50px
}
div{
    height: 45px;
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #50b3cf;
}
div::after{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.5px solid transparent;
    right: 1px;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    border-left: 22.5px solid #50b3cf;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Declare values for the *pseudo-element* `width` & `height`
   properties;
2. purge the borders;
3. then rotate the *pseudo-element* in question;
4. now apply `box-shadow` as required;
5. grab a nice cold one;

```css
body{
   padding:50px
}
div{
    height: 45px;
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #50b3cf;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #000000;
}
div::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    content: "";
    left: 100%;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #50b3cf;
    transform: rotate(46deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 5px 0px #000000;
}
div::before { /* ver 2.0 Patch */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #50b3cf;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 25px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's a nice trick :)

Comment: @sjahan One to put in the bag with all the others

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError when i run the above code, i am not able to see the box shadow

Comment: @codegeek Do you mean that you can't see it in the code snippet embedded in my answer or when you try to apply the styles in my answer to your production code?
Take a close look, compare versions, and make sure you haven't missed anything. The significant changes have been applied to the *pseudo-element*, the only addition to the `div` selector is the `box-shadow` rule added for the "full-effect". Other than this, I can't say - I can only account for what I'm given to work with.

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError i can't see it in the code snippet

Comment: @codegeek Inspect the element and try to adjust the opacity of the `box-shadow` properties. Your monitor might be trying to play a trick on your eyes ;)

Comment: @codegeek Come right yet? What's the update?

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError this works thanks

Comment: Rock and roll, good to know!

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError how you have calculated the width and height of the pseudo elements to be 32 exactly.so that if it rotates it properly fits as an arrow

Comment: With a little hack; I replicated your styles for the *pseudo-element* `:after` and created another *pseudo-element* `:before`, then applied those styles copied from `:after` (before any changes were made) to the newly crated `:before`, so that I could use `:before` as a reference. With `:before` below `:after`, I could adjust the height and width to precision.\

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box{
 border:1px solid white;
 width:400px;
 height:150px; 
 margin-left:40px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 9px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.arrow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   top:20px;
   left:-100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     transform: rotate(270deg);  
}
.arrow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: white;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   top: 76px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -2px -2px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="arrow"></div>
 </div>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this what you are looking to do.

The first one with box shadow, the second one doesn't has box shadow but you can add it using this code `box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #000;`in class "arrow-r"

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .main-box{
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 35px 90px;
}
.box{
  font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding: 13px 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.arrow-l {

  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #08abf4;    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #000;

}
.arrow-r {

  float: right;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;

}
.box:before{
      position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    content: '\00a0';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(-36deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg) skew(-36deg);
}
.box.left:before {
  left: -4px;
  background-color: #08abf4;

}

.box:before{
      position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    content: '\00a0';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(-36deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg) skew(-36deg);
}
.box.right:before {
  right: -4px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

</style>

<div class="main-box">
  <div class="box arrow-l left">
                    I'm Liam Lababidi
                </div>
    <div class="box arrow-r right">
                    What about u?
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to use `box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;` for this. Each px indicates what side and the # indicates the color.

```css
body{
   padding:50px
}
div{
    height: 45px;
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #50b3cf;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}
div::after{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.5px solid transparent;
    right: 1px;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    border-left: 22.5px solid #50b3cf;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You can see that the shadow here doesn't follow the custom shape. I guess OP already knows about `box-shadow`.